# Modify jquery full calendar extenal event by using date picker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, fullcalendar

Can someone give me advice for below functionality is possible with jquery full calendar.

Once we drop a external event in to a date block, is it possible to extant the event by using a external date picker?

Eg:

1. Dropped a event in to 02 May 2014.
2. If user click on the event, a popup will show jquery Ui date picker.
3. If user select the date to 05 may 2014, the event also should extend automatically to 5th.

Comment: yes, that can be done... try it.. :) and come back if you have problems with the codes...

Comment: @Reigel Is it possible to provide a sample code or reference link. Or which method should I use?

Answer (score 1):

I would utilize eventClick method to open a jquery ui dialog that contains a single text input with datepicker called on it.  Utilizing the onSelect method of the datepicker you can update the start and end values of the event object passed to eventClick method.  Then you can call the updateEvent method of fullcalendar passing it the same updated event.

```
eventClick: function(event){
    var input = $('<input type="text" id="datepicker" />');
    var $dialog = $('<div/>').dialog({autoOpen:true, modal:true});
    $dialog.append(input);
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({onSelect: function(date){
        // you'll have to manually format the date value
        // into something fullcalendar understands
        // I don't remember off the top of my head what 
        // format onSelect returns to you or what
        // fullcalendar requires.
        event.start = date;
        $calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
    }});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replay, I'll run "updateEvent" in loop, also want to sure user can remove event by selecting previous date.

Comment: fullcalendar handles all the display stuff when you select different dates.  Just make sure to use the built it methods.

Comment: But How I can remove event by if user reduce date range. Is it possible like $calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', '') ?